# Return complete cases of sf object in R

Tags: r, unique, distinct, r-sf

What is the equivalent of `df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]` for `sf` objects?

I know `sf` objects behave mostly like dataframes with a "sticky" `geometry` column, but running the above code returns the following error:

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]

Error in complete.cases(df) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

This is likely due to `sf` objects storing their `geometry` variables as lists. Your input is appreciated!

Comment: So you're looking for `sf` objects with NA geometry? Or geometries with NA elements?

Comment: Both are problematic. I only want observations with elements and geometries.

Comment: `complete.cases` is pretty much broken for data frames with anything beyond simple vectors in it. POSIXlt dates, for example. https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sf::st_is_empty()` to check for empty geometries

```
library(sf)

pt1 <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point())
pt2 <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(c(0,0)))

sf <- sf::st_sf(geometry = c(pt1, pt2))

sf[!sf::st_is_empty(sf), ]

# imple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 0 ymax: 0
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# geometry
# 1 POINT (0 0)
```

Comment: This works for missing geometries, but doesn't handle missing attribute data. Piping this result into an `na.omit()` does the trick though! Thanks!

`sf[!sf::st_is_empty(sf), ] %>% na.omit()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a dataset with missing geometries to test this with, but maybe something like:

```
lapply(sfd$geometry, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
```

Will check if there are any NA elements in a geometry. You can use the resulting vector to index your data frame and drop missing entries.

Comment: Where does `pull` come from? Is it doing `sfd$geometry`?

Comment: @Spacedman I updated my answer to use base R. `dolyr::pull` is basically the same as `$`.